# Convert multiple pdf files in a folder into jpgs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, jpeg

I have Python 3.6 and want to know how to convert  30+ pdf images into jpgs. I have these pdf images stored in one folder and would like to run a script to run through all the pdfs, convert them to jpgs and split them out into a new folder.

I tried to test this out on one image (see code below):

```
import pdf2jpg as pdf2jpg

inputpath = r"C:\Users\Admin-dsc\Documents\Image project\pdfinputs\RWG003209_2 Red.pdf"
outputpath = r"C:\Users\Admin-dsc\Documents\Image project\jpgoutputs"

result = pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(inputpath, outputpath, pages="1")
print(result)
```

but I keep getting the following error message which I don't understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-050be63282af>", line 11, in <module>
    result = pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(inputpath, outputpath, pages="1")

AttributeError: module 'pdf2jpg' has no attribute 'convert_pdf2jpg'
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am very new to Python.

Comment: The error means the module `pdf2jpg` doesn't have an object named `convert_pdf2jpg` for you to reference.  Either it's a typo (remember Python is case sensitive) or you're trying to reference another object deeper within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to use `from pdf2jpg import pdf2jpg` instead of `import pdf2jpg as pdf2jpg` - these are two different statements.